Problem with Raycasting Accuracy on RenderTexture Based on Touch Position in Unity VR
I am encountering a problem with a RenderTexture that displays the perspective of other players on a panel in my Unity VR multiplayer project. The feature is implemented such that when the panel is touched with the right hand, a ray is cast into the virtual space corresponding to the touched position. However, the direction of the ray deviates from the touch position, causing it to not work as intended.
Environment:
Device: Meta Quest 3
No hand tracking, using a controller
Hand is displayed in the virtual environment
Goal:
I want to accurately hit targets in the virtual space by casting rays corresponding to the touch position on the panel object with the RenderTexture.
Problem Details:
The touch position on the panel is normalized (bottom left is (0,0), top right is (1,1)), and a ray is cast using a camera showing the RenderTexture, but especially when the camera and panel are at a 180-degree angle (around 1:19 in the video), the touch position and the ray are symmetrically misaligned. For debugging purposes, a red cube is generated at the touch position, and it is also confirmed that the cube position is off.
Reference Video
Relevant Code:
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class PanelManager : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    public Camera displayRenderCamera; // Camera rendering the image to the RenderTexture
    private GameObject displayGameObject; // GameObject displaying the RenderTexture
    private bool collisionStatus = false;
    private Vector3 colliderPoint = Vector3.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        InitializeCameraAndPanel();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        bool gripHeld = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryHandTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        bool triggerNotPressed = !OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);

        if (gripHeld && triggerNotPressed && collisionStatus)
        {
            InteractWithRenderTexture();
        }
        InitializeCameraAndPanel();
    }

    private void InitializeCameraAndPanel()
    {
        PhotonView[] allPhotonViews = FindObjectsOfType<PhotonView>();

        foreach (PhotonView view in allPhotonViews)
        {
            if (view.Owner != null)
            {
                if (view.Owner.ActorNumber != PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber)
                {
                    // Find the other player's camera
                    GameObject camera = view.gameObject.transform.Find("Head/ViewCamera")?.gameObject;
                    if (camera != null)
                    {
                        displayRenderCamera = camera.GetComponent<Camera>();
                        Debug.Log(displayRenderCamera);
                    }
                }
                else if (view.Owner.ActorNumber == PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber)
                {
                    GameObject panel = view.gameObject.transform.Find("Panel/Panel")?.gameObject;
                    if (panel != null)
                    {
                        displayGameObject = panel;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.LogWarning("Panel/Panel not found on my object");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void InteractWithRenderTexture() // Main logic
    {
        Vector3 localHitPoint = getLocalHitPoint();
        // var displayGameObjectSize = displayGameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size;
        Vector3 displayGameObjectSize = new Vector3(0.55f, 0.38f, 0.001f);

        // Calculate the viewport
        var viewportPoint = new Vector3()
        {
            x = (localHitPoint.x / displayGameObjectSize.x) + 0.5f,  // Center at 0.5
            y = (localHitPoint.y / displayGameObjectSize.y) + 0.5f,  // Center at 0.5
        }; // Range: 0-1

        float angleBetween = Vector3.Angle(displayRenderCamera.transform.forward, displayGameObject.transform.forward);

        // Adjust x coordinate based on the angle
        viewportPoint.x = AdjustedCoordinate(angleBetween, viewportPoint.x);

        // Generate a ray from the camera based on the viewport
        Ray ray = displayRenderCamera.ViewportPointToRay(viewportPoint);
        RaycastHit hit;

        // Get the coordinates of the hit point (for debugging)
        // Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(2.0f);
        // GameObject Cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        // Cube.transform.position = point;
        // Cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        // Cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        // Destroy(Cube, 0.1f);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10.0f))
        {
            // Activate the particle system of the detected object
            var cubeManager = hit.transform.GetComponent<CubeManager>();
            if (cubeManager != null)
            {
                cubeManager.StartParticleSystem();
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 getLocalHitPoint() // Get the local coordinates of the touched point on the panel
    {
        Vector3 localHitPoint = colliderPoint;
        if (localHitPoint != Vector3.zero)
        {
            return localHitPoint - displayGameObject.transform.position;
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    public static float AdjustedCoordinate(float theta, float x)
    {
        if (theta == 180.0f) return 1.0f - x;
        if (theta == 0.0f) return x;

        float adjustmentFactor = Mathf.Cos(theta * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        float adjustedX = (1 - adjustmentFactor) * (1 - x) + adjustmentFactor * x;
        return adjustedX;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "rightHand")
        {
            collisionStatus = true;
            colliderPoint = other.ClosestPointOnBounds(transform.position);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "rightHand")
        {
            collisionStatus = false;
            colliderPoint = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}


What I Have Tried:
I have reviewed the method for calculating the touch position in the local coordinate system, but the deviation persists.
Any advice on the cause and solution to this problem would be appreciated. If there's a problem with this implementation, how should it be fixed?
Additional Notes:
My Fixed Code is here.
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PanelManager : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    public Camera displayRenderCamera; // Camera rendering the image to the RenderTexture
    private RawImage displayGameObject; // Display panel as a RawImage
    private Vector3? colliderPoint = null; // Nullable Vector3 to represent the collision point

    void Start()
    {
        InitializeCameraAndPanel();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        bool gripHeld = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryHandTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        bool triggerNotPressed = !OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);

        if (gripHeld && triggerNotPressed && colliderPoint != null)
        {
            InteractWithRenderTexture();
        }
        InitializeCameraAndPanel();
    }

    private void InitializeCameraAndPanel()
    {
        PhotonView[] allPhotonViews = FindObjectsOfType<PhotonView>();

        foreach (PhotonView view in allPhotonViews)
        {
            if (view.Owner != null)
            {
                if (view.Owner.ActorNumber != PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber)
                {
                    GameObject camera = view.gameObject.transform.Find("Head/ViewCamera")?.gameObject;
                    if (camera != null)
                    {
                        displayRenderCamera = camera.GetComponent<Camera>();
                        Debug.Log(displayRenderCamera);
                    }
                }
                else if (view.Owner.ActorNumber == PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber)
                {
                    GameObject panel = view.gameObject.transform.Find("Panel/Panel")?.gameObject;
                    if (panel != null)
                    {
                        displayGameObject = panel.GetComponent<RawImage>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.LogWarning("Panel/Panel not found on my object");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void InteractWithRenderTexture() // Main logic
    {
        if (colliderPoint == null) return;

        Vector3 worldSpaceHitPoint = colliderPoint.Value;

        Vector2 localHitPoint = displayGameObject.rectTransform.InverseTransformPoint(worldSpaceHitPoint);

        var rect = displayGameObject.rectTransform.rect;
        Vector2 textureCoord = localHitPoint - rect.min;
        textureCoord.x *= displayGameObject.uvRect.width / rect.width;
        textureCoord.y *= displayGameObject.uvRect.height / rect.height;
        textureCoord += displayGameObject.uvRect.min;

        Ray ray = displayRenderCamera.ViewportPointToRay(textureCoord);
        // Making Cube for Debugging
        Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(2.0f);
        GameObject Cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        Cube.transform.position = point;
        Cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        Cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        Destroy(Cube, 0.1f);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 10.0f))
        {
            if (hit.transform.TryGetComponent<CubeManager>(out var cubeManager))
            {
                cubeManager.StartParticleSystem();
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("rightHand"))
        {
            var plane = new Plane(transform.forward, transform.position);

            colliderPoint = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(other.bounds.center);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("rightHand"))
        {
            colliderPoint = null;
        }
    }
}


Are you sure your getLocalHitPoint is correct in the first place? Why not use e.g. displayGameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(colliderPoint)? And further there is Camera.WorldToViewportPoint ..

@derHugo Thank you.I didn't know about that function. I'll give it a try and let you know the results!

I tried following your advice, but the problem still persists. Could you please share the updated function in full, rather than just comments? @derHugo

So in general what you would do is

Get the correct touching point in 3D
Get the local point in the RawImage space
Convert that local point to a UV (= Viewport) coordinate
Shoot a ray through the second camera

So I think the first issue is
colliderPoint = other.ClosestPointOnBounds(transform.position);

the transform.position is always somewhere around the center of your panel. I would probably go the other way round and rather get the position of the hand onto the RawImage. For instance just use a Plane and do something like
private Vector3? colliderPoint = null;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("rightHand"))
    {
        var plane = new Plane(transform.forward, transform.position);

        colliderPoint = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(other.bounds.center);
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("rightHand"))
    {
        colliderPoint = null;
    }
}

now this should be a more accurate 3D point of collision.
And then something like
private RawImage displayGameObject;

private void InteractWithRenderTexture() // Main logic
{
    if(colliderPoint == null) return;

    var worldSpaceHitPoint = colliderPoint.Value;

    // 2. convert to local space
    Vector2 localHitPoint = displayGameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldSpaceHitPoint);

     // 3. convert to UV coordinate - see https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/198782/how-do-you-get-the-texture-coordinate-hit-by-the-mouse-on-a-ui-raw-image-in-unit
    var rect = displayGameObject.rectTransform.rect;
    Vector2 textureCoord = localHitPoint - rect.min;
    textureCoord.x *= displayGameObject.uvRect.width / rect.width;
    textureCoord.y *= displayGameObject.uvRect.height / rect.height;
    textureCoord += displayGameObject.uvRect.min;


    // 4. raycast through second camera
    var ray = displayRenderCamera.ViewportPointToRay(viewportPoint);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 10.0f))
    {
        // Activate the particle system of the detected object
        if(hit.transform.TryGetComponent<CubeManager>(out var cubeManager))
        {
            cubeManager.StartParticleSystem();
        }
    }
}


Thank you for your suggestion! I hadn't thought of that approach. However, even after incorporating your suggested code, it didn't work. I'm trying to touch the cube through the panel and activate its particle system, but currently, nothing happens when I touch it. Could you please take a look and see what's going wrong? I apologize for asking so many questions, as I'm a beginner in Unity, but your help is greatly appreciated. You can find the project's GitHub page here:https://github.com/Yumekawa-chan/RemoteCollaboration_base_app/blob/main/Assets/Scripts/PanelManager.cs

And, I've added the code incorporating your suggestions in the question.

Hello derHugo,
I hope you're well. I've tried implementing your suggestions for my Unity issue, but still, nothing happens when I touch the cube through the panel. Could you possibly take a moment to look at my latest code? Your insights are invaluable, and any further guidance or a quick check would be extremely helpful!
Here's the updated code on GitHub for more context: github.com/Yumekawa-chan/RemoteCollaboration_base_app/blob/main/…
Thank you so much for your time and assistance. I really appreciate it!
Best regards,
Yumekawa-chan
